# Add footer link without domain from xml layout

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm trying to add a tel: href to a footer with the next code:

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="telefon">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">0728 947 887
                                </argument>
                                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">tel:0728947887</argument>          
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
```

The link generates but it comes like: https://domain.com/tel:0728947887

In order for the tel: to work, I simply need it to be tel:0728947887

I also tried adding this to the block but the href did not change:

```
 <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="href" xsi:type="string">tel:0728947887</item>
                                </argument>
```

I'd appreciate any ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately all footer links added via layout xml generate urls prefixed with base url because of this method : `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link::getHref()`.
But the workaround is to create a phtml template and assing it to your block. then you should be able to render the link as you wish.

Create the template called `phone.phtml` in one of your modules and change the layout xml to this

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="telefon" template="Vendor_Module::phone.phtml">
      <arguments>
         <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">0728 947 887</argument>
         <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">tel:0728947887</argument>          
       </arguments>
 </block>
```

The template file can look like this:

```
<li>
     <a href="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPath()) ?>">
         <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel());?>
     </a>
</li>
```